# How to update app with parse server queries in android

Tags: android-studio, parse-server

I am practicing to build an app. I want to display all contents of one table of my parser server to my app listview in real time.any help please.

Comment: StackOverflow is meant for more specific programming related questions. However, you'd learn a lot by reading through this guide! http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/  Remember, your first resource should be product documentation.

Comment: @JakeT. Thanks alot... I just set a timer and kept refreshing the page...